# Pthread watchdog: kill and recreate stuck thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, kill, watchdog

I created a watchdog that runs on a thread and checks whether a *still_alive* flag is true. This flag is set true by the thread controlled by the watchdog (at the end of its infinite loop) and set to false by the watchdog. Everything is protected by a mutex.
By (with low frequency) checking *still_alive*, the watchdog can realize if a thread is stuck somewhere (i.e.: it did not update *still_alive* flag).

Now, I would like to take actions whenever a thread is stuck. This should never happen, but sometimes it does, and I would like to have a contingency plan for such circumstances.

How can I cleanly kill the unresponsive thread and recreate it, if that is a good idea at all?

Comment: You did not post a code. No one can answer without seeing your effort.

Comment: You can use `pthread_kill`. Whether that's a good idea depends on what the thread's doing and whether it'd clean after itself properly, etc. Generally, I'd suggest designing such a way that a thread cleanly exits on its own (say it responds to a cv/signal or a flag, etc) and doesn't need to be killed.

Comment: There is the danger that the contingency plan will introduce yet more issues.  The only good way to proceed is to debug the thread to find out how and why it gets stuck.  Even if you manage to safely kill and recreate the thread, (and I have no experience of that because it's too dangerous to try), you will never know what damage the killed thread might have done before you killed it.  For all the rest of your development, you will need to add 'unknown side-effect from misbehaving thread' and 'unknown side-effect of killing misbehaving thread' to the list of possible causes of any bug:((

Comment: There are, of course, things that an unscrupulous developer, or one facing a failed-milestone contractual disaster, might do. Purely hypothetically, one might design the thread operation in the manner of a pool, accepting work via a producer-consumer queue, and create 50 threads.  That might push the MTBF up from a disatrous once-a-day average up to tbe point where it is covered up by monthly OS reboots.  Of course, I would never do such a thing or recommend it to any other developer..